# How to perform knn Search in Spring boot with elastic search

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch, knn

```
    String hostname = "localhost";
    int port = 9200;

    RestHighLevelClient client = new RestHighLevelClient(
            RestClient.builder(new HttpHost(hostname, port, "http")));
    SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest("book");
    SearchSourceBuilder sourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();

    Map<String,Object> params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put("field", "name");
    params.put("query_vector", "Harry potter");
    params.put("k", "3");

    String scriptSource = "double distance = 0;\n" +
            "for (def field : doc.keySet()) {\n" +
            "    if (field == params.field || field == 'query_vector' || field == 'k') continue;\n" +
            "    distance += Math.abs(Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(doc[field])) - Double.parseDouble(params.query_vector));\n" +
            "}\n" +
            "return 1.0 / (distance + 1e-10);";

    //ScriptQueryBuilder scriptQuery = QueryBuilders.scriptQuery(new Script(scriptSource, ScriptType.INLINE, "painless", params));
    Script script=new Script(ScriptType.INLINE,
            "painless",
            scriptSource,
            params
            );
    ScriptQueryBuilder scriptQuery = QueryBuilders.scriptQuery(script);
    sourceBuilder.query(scriptQuery);
    searchRequest.source(sourceBuilder);

    SearchResponse searchResponse = client.search(searchRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
    System.out.println(searchResponse.getHits());
    return searchResponse.getHits();
```

this is my code I am trying to perform knn search I have an index named **book** and I have field **name** and I am trying to serach wherever the harrypotter is in the name field in my index.
I am passing the field and qiuery vector and k value in Map

I expected the results which has the name harry potter but there is an exception throwing while calling the API

> Elasticsearch exception [type=class_cast_exception, reason=Cannot
> cast from [double] to [boolean].]

and I am not sure where I am trying to cast double to boolean

Answer (score 0):

1. `ClassCastException` in Elasticsearch usually occurs when there is a mismatch between expected data type and data in Elastic index.
2. Anyway doing `kNN`(k-Nearest Neighbors) search directly in Java client is not advised and not good approach. In fact, once I was also required to do so and did,  sharing piece of code where I did implement `kNN Search`:

   ```
   private static Response performKNNSearch(RestClient restClient, String indexName,
                            String vectorField, String value, int k) throws Exception {
        String endpoint = "/" + indexName + "/_search";

        Map<String, Object> knnQuery = new HashMap<>();
        knnQuery.put("field", vectorField);
        knnQuery.put("k", k);
        knnQuery.put("num_candidates", k);

        List<Double> vectorValues = new ArrayList<>();
        String[] vectorComponents = value.replace("[", "").replace("]", "").split(",");
        for (String component : vectorComponents) {
            vectorValues.add(Double.parseDouble(component.trim()));
        }
        knnQuery.put("query_vector", vectorValues);

        Map<String, Object> requestPayload = new HashMap<>();
        requestPayload.put("knn", knnQuery);

        //Serialize the request payload as JSON
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);

        ObjectWriter objectWriter = objectMapper.writer();
        String payloadJSON = objectWriter.writeValueAsString(requestPayload);

        Request request = new Request("POST", endpoint);
        request.setJsonEntity(payloadJSON);

        return restClient.performRequest(request);
    }
   ```

- In the code `vectorField` is the field in `index` that contains `vectors` to search, `value` is the vector value for which the nearest neighbors will be searched, and finally `k` is the number of nearest neighbors to retrieve.

3. Another approach which I would advise as the easiest way and most used one, make `kNN search-template` in `elastic dev tool` and in Java client simply invoke that particular search-template. In this way you just need to change your search-template in dev tool without making hard code changes.

- [Following material](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/knn-search.html) shows you how to make kNN search in dev tool by making search-template.
- After making kNN search template you can call it with the following command and can see the template itself:

[image]

- In Java client as usual make Rest client builder, then to invoke search-template from Elasticsearch you can use the following code part:

  ```
  SearchTemplateRequest request = new SearchTemplateRequest();
        request.setRequest(new SearchRequest("index-name")); 

        request.setScriptType(ScriptType.STORED);
        request.setScript("knn_search_template");

        // Set the template parameters
        Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("queryVector", "[-1, 3, -12]");
        params.put("k", 1);                             
        params.put("numCandidates", 2);
  ```
- `k` represents the number of nearest neighbors to retrieve. It determines how many similar documents will be returned as search result.
- `numCandidates` represents the number of approximate nearest neighbors to consider during the search. It is used to optimize the k-NN search process by limiting the number of candidates that are considered for the final result set.

P.S. You can use both ways, and actually it depends on your requirements, but from my experience using search-templates are much more efficient and keeps code clear. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

There is a `KnnQuery` type available, that can be combined with a `NativeQuery` and thus used by e.g. `ReactiveElasticsearchOperations.search(...)`.

I found the reference in the following discussion.

https://discuss.elastic.co/t/hybrid-search-by-using-knn-and-query-in-java-client/346594